# Take an action after any model is created, updated, or deleted in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to execute a function every time ANY model is created, updated, or deleted in my application.

For example, I want to print the model name and its record data to my log.

How can I do this? I've been looking for some class to extend, but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to your comment on Robok's answer, you can have a `BaseObserver`.

As example, here is the one I use:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class BaseObserver {

    public function saving(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function saved(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function updating(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function updated(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function creating(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function created(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function deleting(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function deleted(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function restoring(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function restored(Eloquent $model) {}
}
```

Now any model observer can extend it:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

use App\Observers\BaseObserver;

class ProductObserver extends BaseObserver {

    public function creating(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $model->author_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    }

    public function created(Eloquent $model)
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('logo')) Image::make(Input::file('logo')->getRealPath())->save(public_path() ."/gfx/product/logo_{$model->id}.png");
    }

    public function updating(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $model->author_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    }

    public function updated(Eloquent $model)
    {
        if(Input::has('payment_types')) $model->paymentTypes()->attach(Input::get('payment_types'));

        //Upload logo
        $this->created($model);
    }
}
```

If you want to have something like `$model->author_id = Sentry::getUser()->id` in every observer, you can of course apply that in the `BaseObserver`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are **model events**: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events

Comment: Right so with model events and observers, I can add actions to individual models. But if I want to add an action to ALL models, is that possible? 

For example, I was looking for some base Model class to extend or use.

Comment: You can always extend Eloquent class.