# Intercepting laravel 5 model save for unique constraint check

Tags: php, laravel, unique

I have a 3 column unique restraint to check before saving an entry.

In my case an entry is unique for a product_id, a product_attribute_id, and a product_option value.

For example product 1234 Size L should only have one entry, 1234 Color Orange should only have one entry.

When I double an entry '1-7-Fuscha Baby' in my test I will correctly receive an error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 
1062 Duplicate entry '1-7-Fuscha Baby' for key 'p_a_v' 
(SQL: insert into `product_options` (`product_attribute_id`, `value`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (1, Fuscha Baby, 7, 2016-02-15 13:06:27, 2016-02-15 13:06:27))
```

So now I need to bypass creating that entry

On the ProductOption model, I am overriding the save method to add the check. This is the busted part, can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
public function save()
{
    // before save code - Check for a unique value....
    //

    $product_option = ProductOption::where('product_id', $this->product_id)
        ->where('value' ,$this->value)
        ->where('product_attribute_id',$this->product_attribute_id)
        ->first()
    ;

    if($product_option)
    {
        //i have the constraint violation, now how do I tell laravel to use $product_option instead of $this?
        //return  $product_option;  messy error 1
        //return  $product_option->id; messy error 2
        //$this = $product_option; sytnax error
        //return; I think this works with the plain old save() call, but not for saveMany()
        //$this->exists = true; //works for save(), fails for saveMany()

    }

    parent::save();
    // after save code
}
```

Additionally this should work with the saveMany call:

```
public function saveOptionsArray($product_options)
{
    /*
        $product_options = [
            ['name' => 1, 'value' =>'Pink'],
            ['name' => 'Color', 'value' =>'Yellow'],
            ['name' => 'Color', 'value' =>'Yellow'], //constraint violation
            ['name' => 'Size', 'value' =>'1'],
            ['name' => 'Size', 'value' =>'2'],
            ['name' => 'Size', 'value' =>'3'],
            ];
    */
    $options = [];
    foreach ($product_options as $product_option)
    {
        $option = new ProductOption();
        $option->product_attribute_id = $product_option['name'];
        $option->value = $product_option['value'];
        //$option = $option->checkBeforeSave(); //same as the save() pre-check above.. didn't work out too well
        $options[] = $option;
    }

    return $this->options()->saveMany($options);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are looking for and in the proper Laravel way, you should leverage model events, as such:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        //run your logic here
    });
}
```

`saving` will intercept `create` and `save` operations for the model.

This code should be placed in the model. Later on you can extend and extract it to a model observer.

Comment: Ok , I understand that, however do you think this is more understandable than overriding save in the model as I described? It seems like the way I implemented it kinda gets in there before any events.

Comment: There are many different hooks, `saving`, `saved`, `creating`, `updated`, `deleting`, `restoring`, etc. Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28620785/2094178

Answer (score 0):

Got it, basically return false......

However, if the string is too long the code again fails, so i'll pass on my truncator as well...

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    // before save code - Check for a unique value....
    // before check for unique, the value will truncate causing another issue...

    $product_option = ProductOption::where('product_id', $this->product_id)
        ->where('value' ,$this->truncateString('value'))
        ->where('product_attribute_id',$this->product_attribute_id)
        ->first()
    ;
    if($product_option)
    {
        return false;
    }

    parent::save();
    // after save code
}
```

And the truncator which will read the max length from the db and chop your input before the entry does causing another constraint violation

```
public function truncateString($column)
{
    $max_length =  DB::connection()->getDoctrineColumn($this->getTable(), $column)->getLength();
    $this->$column  = substr ( $this->$column , 0 ,$max_length );
    return $this->$column;

}
```